# How to find the number of events for the first 24 hours for each user id

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, row-number, with-statement

I'm working on snowflake to solve a problem. I wanted to find the number of events for the first 24 hours for each user id.

This is a snippet of the database table I'm working on. I modified the table and used a date format without the time for simplification purposes.

| user_id | client_event_time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-28 |
| 1 | 2022-07-29 |
| 1 | 2022-08-21 |
| 2 | 2022-07-29 |
| 2 | 2022-07-30 |
| 2 | 2022-08-03 |

I used the following approach to find the minimum event time per user_id.

```
SELECT user_id, client_event_time,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY client_event_time) row_number,
       MIN(client_event_time) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) MinEventTime
FROM Data
ORDER BY user_id, client_event_time;
```

| user_id | client_event_time | row_number | MinEventTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-28 | 1 | 2022-07-28 |
| 1 | 2022-07-29 | 2 | 2022-07-28 |
| 1 | 2022-08-21 | 3 | 2022-07-28 |
| 2 | 2022-07-29 | 1 | 2022-07-29 |
| 2 | 2022-07-30 | 2 | 2022-07-29 |
| 2 | 2022-08-03 | 3 | 2022-07-29 |

Then I tried to find the difference between the minimum event time and client_event_time, and if the difference is less than or equal to 24, I counted the client_event_time.

```
with NewTable as (
        (SELECT user_id,client_event_time, event_type,
        row_number() over (partition by user_id order by CLIENT_EVENT_TIME) row_number,
        MIN(client_event_time) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) MinEventTime
        FROM Data
        ORDER BY user_id, client_event_time))
    
SELECT user_id,  
        COUNT(case when timestampdiff(hh, client_event_time, MinEventTime) <= 24  then 1 else 0 end) AS duration
FROM    NEWTABLE
GROUP BY user_id
```

I got the following result:

| user_id | duration |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |

I wanted to find the following result:

| user_id | duration |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |

Could you please help me solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You mention hours, but you don't have time in the sample data. Regardless, you would use a subquery or CTE to get the min(time) per user, then join on user and count(*) from data where (insert datediff logic here). Output would be UserID and COUNT if that's what you're looking for. No need for row_number or case expression  per the title of the question.

Comment: If you just need total number of events for 24 hours you can simply do something like `select user_id, count(*) from Data  where TIMEDIFF(client_event_time, NOW()) <= 24 group by user_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier done with a `qualify`

```
with cte as
(select *
 from mytable
 qualify event_time<=min(event_time) over (partition by user_id) + interval '24 hours')

select user_id, count(*) as counts
from cte
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a problem for windowed functions! I like them a lot.

Here's you sample data

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (user_id INT, client_event_time DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @table (user_id, client_event_time) VALUES
(1, '2022-07-28 13:30:00'),
(1, '2022-07-29 08:30:00'),
(1, '2022-08-21 12:34:56'),
(2, '2022-07-29 08:30:00'),
(2, '2022-07-30 13:30:00'),
(2, '2022-08-03 12:34:56')
```

I added some hours to it, so we can look at 24 hour windows more easily. For user_id 1 we can see they had 2 events in the 24 hours after their initial one.  For user_id 2 there was only the first one. We can capture that with a MIN OVER, along with the actual datetimes.

```
SELECT user_id, MIN(client_event_time) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) AS FirstEventDateTime, client_event_time
  FROM @table
```

```
user_id FirstEventDateTime      client_event_time
-------------------------------------------------------
1       2022-07-28 13:30:00.000 2022-07-28 13:30:00.000
1       2022-07-28 13:30:00.000 2022-07-29 08:30:00.000
1       2022-07-28 13:30:00.000 2022-08-21 12:34:56.000
2       2022-07-29 08:30:00.000 2022-07-29 08:30:00.000
2       2022-07-29 08:30:00.000 2022-07-30 13:30:00.000
2       2022-07-29 08:30:00.000 2022-08-03 12:34:56.000
```

Now we have the first datetime and each rows datetime in the resultset together, we can make a comparison:

```
SELECT user_id, MIN(client_event_time) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) AS FirstEventDateTime, client_event_time, CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR,MIN(client_event_time) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id), client_event_time)  < 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS EventsInFirst24Hours
  FROM @table
```

```
user_id FirstEventDateTime      client_event_time       EventsInFirst24Hours
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       2022-07-28 13:30:00.000 2022-07-28 13:30:00.000 1
1       2022-07-28 13:30:00.000 2022-07-29 08:30:00.000 1
1       2022-07-28 13:30:00.000 2022-08-21 12:34:56.000 0
2       2022-07-29 08:30:00.000 2022-07-29 08:30:00.000 1
2       2022-07-29 08:30:00.000 2022-07-30 13:30:00.000 0
2       2022-07-29 08:30:00.000 2022-08-03 12:34:56.000 0
```

Now we have an indicator telling us which events occurred in the first 24 hours, all we really need is to sum it, but SQL Server is mean about using a windowed function in another aggregate, so we need to cheat and put it into a subquery.

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(EventsInFirst24Hours) AS CountOfEventsInFirst24Hours
  FROM (
        SELECT user_id, MIN(client_event_time) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) AS FirstEventDateTime, client_event_time, CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR,MIN(client_event_time) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id), client_event_time)  < 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS EventsInFirst24Hours
          FROM @table 
       ) a
 GROUP BY user_id
```

And that gets us to the result:

```
user_id CountOfEventsInFirst24Hours
-----------------------------------
1       2
2       1
```

A little about what's going on with the windowed function:
`MIN` - the aggregation we want it to do. The common aggregate functions have windowed counterparts.
`(client_event_time)` - the value we want to do it to.
`OVER (PARTITION BY user_id)` - the window we want to set up. In this case we want to know the minimum datetime for each of the user_ids.
We can partition by as many columns as we'd like.
You can also use an ORDER BY with as many columns as you'd like, but that was not necessary here. Ex:
`OVER (PARTITION BY column1, column2 ORDER BY column4, column5 DESC)`
Partition (or group by) column1 and column2 and order by column4 and column5 descending.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count of events around 24 hours of the minimun event time, you canuse a group by CTE that givbes you all the minumum event tomes for all users

the rest  is to get all the rows that are in the tme limit

```
WITH min_data as
(SELECT user_id,MIN(client_event_time) mindate FROM data GROUP BY user_id)
  SELECT d.user_id, COUNT(*) 
  FROM data d JOIN min_data md ON d.user_id = md.user_id WHERE client_event_time <= mindate + INTERVAL '24 hour'
GROUP BY d.user_id
ORDER BY d.user_id
```

| user_id | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |